# CQRS C#,Whats the Purpose of EventSource Repository For Reconstituing the Object,Why Cannt we Use Acctual Database for Resocnstituting the object

Tags: c#, cqrs

CQRS C#,Whats the Purpose of EventSource Repository For Reconstituting the Object,Why Can't we Use Actual Database for Reconstituting the object.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591577.aspx#sec4

Comment: Really - you can do whatever you want. Good luck with all that.

Comment: In an event sourced system, the Event Store is the source of truth. It is the "actual database."

Comment: Apart from CQRS pattern,what if have different database to capture the actual data and diiferent database for eventsource ,in this case ,how do we reconsittute the object?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

> Why Can't we Use Actual Database for Reconstituting the object.

You can.  The CQRS pattern and "event sourcing" are two separate ideas.

*CQRS* and *Event Sourcing* tend to be talked about in combination because (a) they happen to fit together very well, and (b) Greg Young, who first articulated the CQRS pattern, *also* promotes the use of event sourcing/event stores for a number of different reasons.

So if you read a lot about CQRS, you are also likely to read a lot of arguments supporting event sourcing.  The reverse is also true.

But the coupling isn't required.  If persisting/retrieving snapshots of your write model is a better fit for your current requirements than persisting/retrieving event histories, then *do that*.  Horses for courses.

(Note: even when using event stores, it is a known pattern to replace "load all of history and rebuild object from scratch" with "load a snapshot of the object, then apply only the events since the snapshot was made" in designs where objects can have many events in their history and there isn't a reasonable way to refactor that history into many shorter histories.)

> How do you commit the transaction between EventStore Repository and Write Model Repository?

You *don't*.

If you want the book of record (ie, the source from which the write model reconstitutes the object) to be the "actual database", the the event history schema is implemented in the actual database also, and you write both in a single transaction.  See [Reliable Messaging without Distributed Transactions](https://vimeo.com/111998645) for an overview.

If you want the book of record to be the event store, then that *is* the actual database.  You write the events, and do not write the current state of the actual object at all (you might cache the current state in memory for your next update, but if the cache entry is invalidated, you reconstruct it from the history, rather than a persisted representation of the state).  This is the most common persistence pattern for event sourcing -- the "event store repository" and the "write model repository" are the same store.

If you want the book of record to be the event store, and the time required to rehydrate the object is unacceptable to the business, then you write the events into the event store repository in the current transaction, and then later (not part of this transaction, you load an old snapshot, create a new snapshot by applying the more recent events available in the event store, then write a new version of the snapshot (along with meta data about what point in the event sequence this snapshot represents).  When reconstituting the write model, you look for the latest available snapshot, then apply "the rest" of the events from the event store on top, and proceed from there.

There aren't any miracles here - just a bunch of trade offs you can make to improve the cost benefit ratio in your design.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Comment: In CQRS C#,How do you commit the transaction between EventStore Repository and Write Model Repository,example If Events Get Saved and Commands Gets Failed in Write Repository,How do you commit or Rollback the Transactions in both model